Lingering Node Version raises issues when using npm
For the longest time, I have been getting this strange node issue where no matter what node I use, when running npm my computer bugs out and runs into issues regarding Node.js v17.9.1.
When trying to do npm start on school assignment
When trying to do npm run dev on side project
I tried deleting and reinstalling all of node, updated nvm, tried everything, yet this still pops up. I've gone through two of my SWE friends as well and they haven't been able to diagnose it either.
Installing with npm works, but only issue is when I try to run the program with npm. So basically I am unable to run any node project locally.
I've gotten around using yarn, but for this assignment I'm working on in class, I don't think that's an option.
I'm using an M1 MacBook Pro if that helps?
Deleting and reinstalling all of node
Deleting, reinstalling, updating nvm
